# What is the point of making separate public functions for getting/setting a private value?

Tags: c#, return-value, private, public

*Let me just preface this by saying that I know this is probably a newbie quesion, I tried searching for it and I can't find a proper anwser for it (probbably asking it wrong).*

So usually when I want to use another value outisde of its class, I just make it public and access it lik.

Yet often I see other code use private values in their class and then make separate functions for getting and setting the value like so:

```cs
private bool fooBar;

public void SetFooBar(bool boolean)
{
   fooBar = boolean;
}

public bool GetFooBar()
{
   return fooBar;
}
```

Excuse my ignorance but what exactly is the point of it? They both do essentially the same thing (by my newbie logic atleast). I know that private variables are useful in that it ensures you can't break the functionality of a program by modifying them elsewhere in the code, but you're modifying them elsewhere in the code anyway, so what gives? Why do I see people do this?

Comment: In C# you should be using properties instead of Get/Set methods, but the general point is to hide the implementation of how the value is saved internally and makes it easier to make non-breaking changes.

Comment: You should not generally make a field `public`, but should make it a public property (i.e: `public bool FooBar { get; set; }`). Using methods to get and set is not typical in c#.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Because directly modifying the state of an object is a no-no in OOP
2. Because you can't put fields into an interface (and once you get far enough, you usually end up accessing most other objects through interfaces)
3. Because it allows additional logic (like raising events) when another object wants to interact with the field
4. Because certain things (like WPF bindings) only work with properties, not fields
5. Because you may want to change how the value is retrieved/stored (not just in-memory) later

(Note that in C# you usually do this as a property, not methods, like `public bool Foo {get; set;}`)

Comment: Thanks for the info, i'll do it through properties next time. I read somewhere that the point of doing it through a method was so the field stays private, and that you you want them private for security reasons or something(?).  That said, if I use `public bool Foo {get; set;}` then I'm essentially making it a public field, correct?

Comment: My mistake, I meant that if I use `public bool Foo {get; set;}` then I'm making it a public property, but how is it different from a public field?

Comment: @Mathue24 Its not really a "security" reason (especially because private members can be accessed through reflection no matter what) and more of a "good design" reason. Properties are different than fields in items 2, 3, 4, and 5 of my answer. **Auto** properties (what I listed) are different in 2 and 4

Answer (score 5):

This allows you to change the way the value is stored regardless of how external users access it.

Using Getter and Setter functions, you could request the data from a local cache or pull it from a database.

C# supports Getter Setter functionality implementations using a property style accessor.

```
private bool _fooBar
public bool FooBar
{
 get { return _fooBar; }
 set {  _fooBar = value; }
}
```

As [BradleyDotNET](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1783619/bradleydotnet) mentioned in the comments, you can write these in a way that [resembles lambdas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) starting with C# 7.0

```
private bool _fooBar
public bool FooBar
{
    get => _fooBar;
    set => _fooBar = value;
}
```

As [BradleyDotNET](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1783619/bradleydotnet) mentioned you can write this exact implementation as

```
public bool FooBar { get; set; }
```

Which will act the same way.

You can also expand upon this by making the value only public to get, but only settable in the class.

```
public bool FooBar { get; protected set; }
```

Comment: And, with C# 7, get can be `get => _fooBar`